# Add and remove class isnt working for foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add and remove a class if an input has a value once a user press submit. I have a class called "qty" thats a dynamic field (the user can add or delete multiple qty inputs).

The html for the input is:

```
<input placeholder='Insert Quantity' value='' name='saved_item[1][qty]' class='qty' type='text'/>
```

But im also trying to change one div that will display the error with a text:

```
<span id="qty-error" class="hide-error">• Please make sure to fill out all item information or delete the item row</span>
```

But it doesn't show despite it showing the "inputerror" class (which turns the border red).

My jquery is:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
$(".qty").each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
                $(this).addClass("inputerror");
                $("#qty-error").removeClass("hide-error");
                $("#qty-error").addClass("show-error");
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
                $("#qty-error").removeClass("show-error");
                $("#qty-error").addClass("hide-error");
            }
        });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this won't help with this specific problem, but instead of rolling your own validation all the time, you might want to look into jQuery Validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're changing the class of `#qty-error` for *each* `.qty`, the class of `#qty-error` will be decided by the status of the *last* `.qty` item.

You can change it to apply the classes to `#qty-error` afterward:

```
$(".qty").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
        $(this).addClass("inputerror");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
    }
});

if ($(".qty.inputerror").length > 0) {
    $("#qty-error").removeClass("hide-error");
    $("#qty-error").addClass("show-error");
}
else {
    $("#qty-error").removeClass("show-error");
    $("#qty-error").addClass("hide-error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works.!

So by checking to the #qty-error afterwards, how does it know to check each individual class for an error? Im not sure what ".length > 0" does here. Would you mind explaining? Again, THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: In the each loop, you are adding (or removing) the class `inputerror` for every `.qty` element. `$(".qty.inputerror")` will retrieve all elements that have both classes `.qty` and `.inputerror`. It's basically checking that there is at least 1 `.inputerror` element.